# Why do I need $(( ... )) in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was following a bash scripting tutorial and came across this code -

```
#!/bin/bash
x=1

while [$x -ne 5]
do
   echo $x
   x=$(($x+1))
done
```

What is the need of $(())? Why can't I just write `x=$x+1` instead of `x=$(($x+1))`? 
Or alternatively why can't I write `x=x+1` as in other languages?

Comment: History, mainly.  The shell manipulated strings only for a long time, doing arithmetic (and some more complex string) manipulation via the `expr` command.  Then the shells acquired some arithmetic capabilities, but the notation had to fit in with the historical behaviour, and the `((...))` and `$((...))` notations were chosen.

Comment: it is just a syntax...  learn to adopt to it, or change it yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html:

> Arithmetic expansion
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
>   and the substitution of the result. The format for arithmetic
>   expansion is:
>
> $(( expression ))
>
> The expression is treated as if it were within double quotes, but a
>   double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially. All
>   tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and quote removal. Arithmetic substitutions may be
>   nested.
>
> If the expression is invalid, Bash prints a message indicating failure
>   to the standard error and no substitution occurs.

edit: I guess x=x+1 doesn't work because it would set x to the string "x+1", thus the need for $(()).

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer the short former of `x=x+1`, you might find it better to use `let` as follows -

```
let x=x+1
```